# Setting text-color on selected tab bar item

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I've created a tab bar application. I have four tabs; on the selected tab, I need to set the color red for tab title. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to customize the color of the text on the `UITabBarItem`s. Unfortunately, it's really not that flexible. If you're intent on doing this (which, unless you've carefully considered the design with the help of a professional, I recommend against!), you'll have to do some really frightening things to get this to work.

I'd suggest iterating through the subviews of the `UITabBar` (as many levels as necessary), and looking for `UILabel` objects. If you find some, you can change their color. If you don't, that means that it is implemented differently (probably in a `-drawRect:` method somewhere); if this happens to be the case, you really ought to give up.

Best of luck on whatever you decide to do.

Answer (score 24):

Using the UIAppearance protocol (iOS5+) this is now possible, and actually pretty easy.

```
[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
        UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor greenColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
        UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor purpleColor] }     forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Please excuse the awful colors!

Comment: Thank you for this answer! For iOS7+, UITextAttributeTextColor has been deprecated and you can use NSForegroundColorAttributeName now.

Answer (score 5):

Anyone who's looking for Swift 4 solution..

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: .red], for: .selected)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what finally worked for me:

1)Selected text color

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:someColor];
```

2)Unselected text(also changes image color)

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:anotherColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to clear things up a bit…

If you'd like to change the appearance for all tab bar items, use:

*Objective-C*:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor :[UIColor someColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

*Swift*:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.someColor()], forState: .Selected)
```

**However**, if you just want to set the appearance of a single item do it like so:

*Objective-C*:

```
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor :[UIColor someColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

*Swift*:

```
tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.someColor()], forState: .Selected)
```

**Note**: `tabBarItem` is a property on `UIViewController`. This means that while every `UIViewController` has this property, it may not be the `tabBarItem` you're looking for. This is often the case when your view controller is enclosed in a `UINavigationController`. In this instance, access the `tabBarItem` on the navigation controller not the one in it's root (or other) view controller.

Answer (score 1):

This is the swift version :-

```
    for item in self.mainTabBar.items! {

    let unselectedItem: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    let selectedItem: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    item.setTitleTextAttributes(unselectedItem as? [String : AnyObject], forState: .Normal)
    item.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedItem as? [String : AnyObject], forState: .Selected)

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

That is possible by `-drawRect:`, but by doing that you are highly increasing chances of your app being rejected by App Store

Comment: What? Drawrect is the standard method for laying out a UIView.